# Searching database by string exploded into array

Tags: php, mysql

To be clear, I need to search the table in database, specifically field called `tags` which is defined as text. Into the database, I am entering those 'tags' as a string and then I am exploding / dividing this string of 'tags' by `explode()` method into array in `php`. But for search of multiple 'tags' in form I need to enter multiple tags divided by SPACE and then by #.

Problem is that I do not know how to tell database to ignore order of entered tags and display all pictures which contains entered tags in search form ignoring the order of entered tags. Until now I was able to search only pictures where tags were in order.

I have tried to do it this way but it did not work

```
$search_string = $_POST['search'];
$exploded_search_string = explode(" ", $search_string);    
$sql_search = "SELECT * FROM pictures 
               WHERE tags LIKE '%".$exploded_search_string."%' 
               ORDER BY ID_picture DESC";
```

Comment: The way you are constructing your SQL query is open to SQL injection, please use Prepared statements, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/60496#60496)

Comment: Explode splits a string into an array.  Not a string.

Comment: It sound like you want to change your query into something like 'WHERE tags LIKE '%$tag1%' AND tags LIKE '%tag2%'' etc. this still seems like a flawed approach.  If say one tag name was contained in another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could do something like this

```
WHERE tags LIKE ’$exploded_search_string[0]%' OR tags LIKE '%$exploded_search_string[1]%'

OR

WHERE tags REGEXP '$exploded_search_string[0]| $exploded_search_string[1]'
```

You can loop the `$exploded_search_string` array to  create the SQL statement like above and your select query should find all the tags found in DB.

Once you be able to get the results using the above statement, you could check FULL TEXT search for an optimized solution.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what database you're using. Assuming you're using MySQL you could take a look at [full-text searching](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-natural-language.html).

Also, you should consider using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) so that you can use prepared statements to help prevent SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

if your tags are identical to the ones in the db, use IN instead of LIKE

```
  $sql_search = "SELECT * FROM pictures 
           WHERE tags IN ($exploded_search_string) 
           ORDER BY ID_picture DESC";
```